# Referencing "this" in Expression trees

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I'm trying out expression trees in C# and just got stuck with something that seems simple, but which is also un-googleable. How can I create an expression that references `this`? `Expression.PropertyOrField(..., "this")` throws an exception "'this' is not a member of type [...]".

The `Expression` class has a boat-load of methods, but none that seems applicable in this case, and it's not a search-friendly problem...

Comment: Can you share some more sample code. What is `...`, what would you expect `this` to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"`this`", in your sample code, is equal to `...`. You already *have* the object reference. There is no hidden member called `this` or something.

`this` conceptually only makes sense in the body of an instance method.

Comment: Hm, that sort of makes sense. But then there is no way to refer to the object in a MemberExpression?

Comment: @carlpett, now I understand! No, there is no way. Since .NET 4 you can use variables and statements in expression trees, so you can first new the object and then initialize its members.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need [`Expression.Constant()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.constant.aspx) method. For example, you can call a class method using expression like this:

```
class Foo
{
    public void Test()
    {
        var instance = Expression.Constant(this);
        var body = Expression.Call(instance, GetType().GetMethod("ToString"));
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(body);
        Console.WriteLine(exp.Compile()());
    }
}
```

Or access instance property:

```
class Foo
{
    public string TestProperty
    {
        get { return "It works."; }
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var instance = Expression.Constant(this);
        var body = Expression.Property(instance, "TestProperty");
        var exp = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(body);
        Console.WriteLine(exp.Compile()());
    }
}
```